# Why am I am getting 500 Error while crawling in javascript

Tags: javascript, lambda

It has worked until yesterday, but now I am getting 500 error at this
site: "https://music.bugs.co.kr/chart/track/day/kpop"
I want to get some information but I can't.

Here's my brief code

```
const Crawler = require('crawler');

exports.daily = async () => {

  var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections: 10,
    callback: function (error, res, done) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      else {
        try{
          console.log(res.statusCode);
        }
        catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
      done();
    }
  });

  // Queue just one URL, with default callback
  let url = 'https://music.bugs.co.kr/chart/track/day/kpop';
  c.queue(url);
}
```

I expect 200 but it throws 500.

I think it is a problem of the site, is there anything I can do?

Comment: A 500 error is an internal server error. You need to look at the server side logs to get the real error message.

Comment: @Quentin I think this url is an external resource to to the asker and he has no access to it

Comment: Yes, that url is not mine

Comment: Well, do you facing 500 right now? Seems like this service is online now, so it should return 200

Comment: @yunzen — Then they should talk to the controller of the external resource. It's their service that is failing with no helpful error message. It could be anything from "Their database is corrupt" to "They noticed the OP making automated requests to their site and IP blocked them". It isn't something that randoms on SO can reasonably debug.

Comment: @Quentin that's true. But remember, this is Q&A not a forum. In the future this question might arise to other persons than the asker and those are in need of help, too. So we maybe should find general answers.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are not the owner if bugs.co.kr.

Error 500 is a sing that something is wrong on the other side (bugs.co.kr). If this is not under your control you cannot do anything directly.

Things you *could* do:

1. Wait! Normally those 500 errors are detected very fast by the remote site owners/developers and being rapidly fixed .
2. Contact the site: File a bug report; Send a bug report email; Fill in the contact form! Anything.
3. Find a different service (ff error isn't fixed) that offers similar data. You may need to rewrite your code.